# sql counting with nested sub query

Tags: mysql

I have a collection of tables in a relational database

```sql
`student_attendences`(`id`, `student_session_id`, `date`, `attendence_type_id`, `remark`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

`student_session`(`id`, `session_id`, `student_id`, `class_id`, `section_id`, `route_id`, `hostel_room_id`, `vehroute_id`, `transport_fees`, `fees_discount`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

`classes`(`id`, `class`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

`sections`(`id`, `section`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

`class_sections`(`id`, `class_id`, `section_id`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

`attendence_type`(`id`, `type`, `key_value`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
```

Based on the above table values i wish to get result of student attendence count class section wise presents, absentee with below join operation i got a result like

```sql
select cl.class, 
       sec.section, 
       att.type AS total 
FROM student_session AS ss, 
     student_attendences AS sa, 
     classes AS cl, 
     sections AS sec, 
     attendence_type AS att, 
     students AS stu 
where sa.student_session_id = ss.id 
  AND cl.id = ss.class_id 
  AND sec.id = ss.section_id 
  AND att.id = sa.attendence_type_id 
  AND stu.id = ss.student_id 
  AND sa.date="2019-12-12"
```

```sql
class | section | total   |
---------------------------
LKG   | A       | Present |
---------------------------
UKG   | A       | Late    |
---------------------------
PREKG | A       | Absent  |
---------------------------
PREKG | B       | Half Day|
---------------------------
```

My expected Result is

```sql
class | section |  present | Absent | Late | Half day |
-------------------------------------------------------
LKG   | A       |  1       | 0      | 0    | 0        |
-------------------------------------------------------
UKG   | A       |  0       | 1      | 0    | 0        |
-------------------------------------------------------
PREKG | A       |  0       | 0      | 1    | 0        |
-------------------------------------------------------
PREKG | B       |  0       | 0      | 0    | 1        |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Please suggest best solution for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ /* uncomment if you need to remove duplicates only */
       cl.class, 
       sec.section, 
       att.type = 'Present' Present,
       att.type = 'Absent' Absent,
       att.type = 'Late' Late,
       att.type = 'Half Day' `Half Day`
       /* , COUNT(*) DupsCount */ /* uncomment if you need to remove and count duplicates */
FROM student_session ss, 
     student_attendences sa, 
     classes cl, 
     sections sec, 
     attendence_type att, 
     students stu 
WHERE sa.student_session_id = ss.id 
  AND cl.id = ss.class_id 
  AND sec.id = ss.section_id 
  AND att.id = sa.attendence_type_id 
  AND stu.id = ss.student_id 
  AND sa.date='2019-12-12'
/* GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6 */ /* uncomment if you need to remove and count duplicates */
```

Calculate total counts:

```sql
SELECT cl.class, 
       sec.section, 
       SUM(att.type = 'Present') Present,
       SUM(att.type = 'Absent') Absent,
       SUM(att.type = 'Late') Late,
       SUM(att.type = 'Half Day') `Half Day`
FROM student_session ss, 
     student_attendences sa, 
     classes cl, 
     sections sec, 
     attendence_type att, 
     students stu 
WHERE sa.student_session_id = ss.id 
  AND cl.id = ss.class_id 
  AND sec.id = ss.section_id 
  AND att.id = sa.attendence_type_id 
  AND stu.id = ss.student_id 
  AND sa.date='2019-12-12'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: I got exact reult

Comment: "class","section","Present","Late","Absent","Holiday","HalfDay"
"PREKG","A","1","0","0","0","0"
"PREKG","A","1","0","0","0","0"
"PREKG","B","1","0","0","0","0"
"PREKG","B","1","0","0","0","0"
"LKG","A","1","0","0","0","0"
"LKG","A","0","0","1","0","0"
"LKG","B","1","0","0","0","0"
"LKG","B","0","1","0","0","0"
"UKG","A","1","0","0","0","0"
"UKG","A","1","0","0","0","0"
"UKG","B","0","1","0","0","0"
"UKG","B","0","1","0","0","0"

Currently i need the count for the column value in single row, Because first two row has similar result that make it one column for similar cases

Comment: this my new issue

Comment: not duplicate entry all entry's are real one if same class and section same attendence type present again add with existing one finally for a single class and section total present total absent etc values i needed can you now understand

Comment: each entry belongs to individual student of particular class and section and my need is individual attendence type total count to respective class and section on particular date in single query

Comment: @sivag Check added query.

Comment: now i got my result